# PySpark - Remove Rows After Groupby?

Tags: python, pyspark

My spark is version 3.0

I have aggregate the data by groupBy(). I want to create a function and a threshold where if the volume of the data is <200 (this would be the threshold), then I want to remove category 'C' from the main table.

How would I do that on PySpark? I thought about creating a list to append 'C', but I am not sure how to do it =/

Image 2 is the expected output.
Can someone help me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have added a 2nd picture to show the expected output. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try with **`groupBy`** and aggregate to get **`sum`()** then **`collect_list`** for **all the values for category** then explode the array.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+----+----+
#|col1|col2|
#+----+----+
#|   A| 250|
#|   A| 250|
#|   A|  50|
#|   B| 250|
#|   B| 250|
#|   B|  50|
#|   C|   5|
#|   C|   5|
#|   C|  10|
#+----+----+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *


df.groupBy("col1").agg(sum(col("col2")).alias("count"),collect_list(col("col2")).alias("col2")).\
filter(col("count") >200).\
select("col1",explode("col2").alias("col2")).\
show()
#+----+----+
#|col1|col2|
#+----+----+
#|   B| 250|
#|   B| 250|
#|   B|  50|
#|   A| 250|
#|   A| 250|
#|   A|  50|
#+----+----+
```